# Можно ли получить img из папки в виде переменной на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, переменные, img

Я новичок в JS и у меня такой вопрос. Можно ли получить картинку из папки в виде переменной на JavaScript а потом использовать эту переменную в `ifelse` ? Если да, то как ?
Спасибо!

Comment: Опишите вопрос подробнее, так как у отвечающих возникают споры и разногласия.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://путь_к_файлу/img/logo.png',
        type: 'HEAD',
        error:
            function(){
                //если нет файла
                alert('Нету файла');
            },
        success:
            function(){
                //если есть файл
                alert('Есть файл');
            }
    });
})
```

Comment: в success можете писать свое условие if/else

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, у меня в работе была похожая ситуация. 
Мы хранили `.svg` картирки в `MondoDB` как строки(`String`). 
При запуске приложения, проверяли id пользователя и доставали `String` из бази проганяли ее через бинарний кодер и вешали на страницу пользователя.

Примерний фиктивний код:

```
    if (Id...) {

       let imageStringFromDB = ...; // String из бази
       let blob = new Blob([imageStringFromDB ], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
       let image = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

       // image - ваша картинка из строки(String)  
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let img = new Image();
img.src = '../img/img.png';

if (img.tagName === "IMG"){
  console.log(true);
} else {
   console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: у вас всегда будет `true`

Comment: и что? суть вопроса была в получении картинки как переменной, а условие он сам напишет

Comment: ваш "ответ" звучит так, словно: я сделал 50% дальше сами, составьте полноценный ответ, раз хотите помочь (проверка на картинку)

Comment: если прочитаете вопрос еще раз, то поймете, что я ответил на него полностью

Comment: @meine: Вы предлагаете автору ответа прочитать мысли ТС, чтобы дополнить пост тем, чего ТС не попросил?